# How to implement axios into vue 3 with composition api with saved baseURL and Headers

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have created a axios.ts file in my plugins folder to store my configuration information for axios as follows:

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $axios: AxiosInstance;
  }
}

// Set config defaults when creating the instance
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://localhost:7281',
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
  });
  
  // Alter defaults after instance has been created
  //instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;

export default api
```

I am unsure what the declare module even does but when i used axios which automatically set axios up it included that ( I am using vuetify 3 project now).

My plugin/index.ts file includes the following:

```
/**
 * plugins/index.ts
 *
 * Automatically included in `./src/main.ts`
 */

// Plugins
import vuetify from './vuetify'
import pinia from '../store'
import router from '../router'
import api from './axios'
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js'
import OktaVue from '@okta/okta-vue'
import oktaConfig from '../oktaConfig'


// Types
import type { App } from 'vue'

export function registerPlugins (app: App) {

  const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(oktaConfig.oidc)

  app
    .use(vuetify)
    .use(router)
    .use(api)
    .use(pinia)
    .use(OktaVue, { oktaAuth })
}
```

My issue is in my implementation i go to use it:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref} from 'vue'
import api from 'axios'

// Override timeout for this request as it's known to take a long time
api.get('/Account', {
  timeout: 5000
}).then(response => {console.log(response)});

</script>
```

I look at the request and its using local host of my vue app which is localhost:3000. I am not sure why implementing axios this way does not carry over the baseuri I set in the config file.

Comment: importing again from axios just gives you another completely default, non-configured instance of axios.  you need to import the instance you configured.  where you did `export default api`, you need to import that from your file `axios.ts`, not from `'axios'`

Comment: Wow how did i miss that lol.... Rookie mistake. It works with the fix.

Comment: @yoduh also it seems the app.use(api) also is not needed. Why is that unlike vue-router and other libraries I use.

Comment: `app.use()` is specifically for registering Vue plugins, which need to "plug in" to the Vue instance to function.  Axios is not a plugin and works independently of Vue.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If you write the correction above regarding the import statements as an answer, il select it.